# iPhone SDK UIBarButton Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, ios4

I have been writing an which works fine but I was testing it with Instruments for leaks and came across leaks from UIBarButtonContent here are the offending lines.

```
     UIButton *searchbutton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [searchbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [searchbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(search) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [searchbutton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 29,29)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchbutton];
```

Am I supposed to release searchButton or self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem anywhere.

Some help would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to release your UIBarButtonItem:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchbutton] autorelease];
```

Comment: @iamsmug -- If you look at the documentation for rightBarButtonItem it will say: `@property(nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem` which means that it will retain the item. Because you alloced it, you also need to release/autorelease it, otherwise the retain count will be 2 and you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release `UIBarButtonItem` reference you have alloc there.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you alloc you are responsible for releasing.  Not sure what happens in your code if you release right after your final line, if you see issues you can try using autorelease instead.

Comment: If I release UIBarButtonItem analyzer says 'The 'release' message should be sent to instances of class 'UIBarButtonItem' and not the class directly'

Comment: iamsung, you can't call release on UIBarButtonItem, you need to call release on the instance of UIBarButtonItem that you created. The way you are creating it, you never have your own pointer to the instance that you can access. You can either use autorelease to deal with this, as shown in my answer, or you can create your own instance in a separate line from where you assign it to the rightBarButtonItem.